# Does synchronizedList.toCollections needs sychronization?

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

```
val listA = Collections.synchronizedList<Int>(mutableListOf())
// ..... some code goes here...
listB = listA.toCollection(mutableListOf())) // Copy the results


// Runs in a different thread
fun A(listA)  {
 listA.add(10)
}
```

Does listA.toCollection needs synchronization?

Comment: Is this Java or Kotlin?  I didn't immediately see a `toCollection()` method in the Java API.

Comment: You can check [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-):  All iterations over the synchronized list must be synchronized to ensure thread safety. Unless `toCollection` does that, you need to do it yourself.

Comment: `toCollection` doesn't do it, so you need to do it yourself.